C++20 Keep typedef struct for operator==
C++20 provides very simple way to compare struct, example I want to typedef my struct in header file this way
typedef struct tfecha {
    int a;
    bool operator==(const tfecha_t&) const = default;
}tfecha_t;

But error: ‘tfecha_t’ does not name a type
error: defaulted member ‘bool tfecha::operator==(const int&) const’ must have parameter type ‘const tfecha&’

Err happen because of typo, use not const tfecha_t& but const tfecha& in line
bool operator==(const tfecha&) const = default;

Full example online
#include <iostream>
typedef struct tfecha {
    int a;
    bool operator==(const tfecha&) const = default;
}tfecha_t;

int main(){
    tfecha_t s1= {.a= 12};
    tfecha_t s2= {.a= 12};
    bool f= s1==s2;
    std::cout << f;
    return 0;
}

